# Access Files in Phone memory on WP 8.1

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing in Windows Phone 8.1. I can use `KnownFolders.RemovableDevices` to access the SD card and I can further retrieve files & folders. Since some WP devices don't have SD cards, how can I access phone memory to retrieve files like the Files app Microsoft made?

Comment: [Here is a very good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758319.aspx) about data and files.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft-built file explorer app has a broader set of capabilities than are available to Windows Phone Store apps. In particular, it has full access to the documents library and unfiltered access to the SD card.